# How to make the mmenu default expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, mmenu

I am using [Jquery mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) for my application. My menu contains sub menus. Sub menus are expanded only when user clicks on the main menu item. I want that expanded by default when user clicks on the menu button. How is this possible? I have initialized as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('mmenu loading');
$("#menu").mmenu({
    slidingSubmenus: false
});
```

});

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: what if there are more than one submenu, do you still want all the menus to open under same main menu ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have only two levels, menu and sub menus. Any way it is better if there is a method to expand even if there are more than two levels.

Comment: You could perhaps save your menu button click into browser's session, and whenever you load the page again, you could check has the menu button been clicked before from the session (sessionStorage object). http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the class ( "mm-opened" ) to the menu which have submenu.

```
<nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                //MENU WITH SUBMENU ADD CLASS mm-opened
                <li class="mm-opened">
                    <a href="#about">About us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#about/team">The team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

AND slidingSubmenus to false.

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    slidingSubmenus: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For always open menu we can add it dynamically. for example  $("#menu").mmenu({
        slidingSubmenus: false

    }).on( "opened.mm", function() {
            var element = $('#menu li');
            element.each(function() {

                $(this).addClass('mm-opened');
            });

        })

Comment: If the expand/collapse interface on the submenu items (that appear as soon as slidingSubmenus is set to false) feel a bit unnecessary it's probably a good idea to now also add the following to the css: 

.mm-next {
 display:none !important;
}